# Setting a first value in a program using scanner

Tags: java, eclipse, user-input

**My Project is as follows:**

The project name of this exercise is AlignedNumbers.

The purpose of this assignment is for you to write more of your own comments and to create methods that are not strictly accessors or mutators. You should also be examining the relationships between

Problem Description

This problem is captured in the book at problem E4.4 and E4.5 (page 168). You are to solve this problem by writing a class called AlignedNumbers. This class will implement each mathematical operation as a separate method. Refer to the book for a description of what each method does.

The AlignedNumbers object created from our class will be tested in your Main.java file. The test should ask the user for two integers and print out the statistics using a method called printStats (this method is not mentioned in the book). The UML diagram for this problem is shown below. Be sure to understand how the UML relates to the code that is present. Notice that the UML and the code match as far as the public interface in concerned.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4455325/sbcc/cs135/img/fundamentalDataTypes/E0402_AlignedNumbers.png

Notice the dependency arrow from Main to AlignedNumbers. This shows you that the Main class requires the AlignedNumbers class to work properly.

Here is a sample of how you will test the code. When the program is run you will ask the user for two integer numbers. Do not worry about error checking; the integer inputs will always be valid.

Input first number: 20
Input second number: 25
You then print all of the statistics using the exact format below. Your printStats method must generate this exact format for any two integers between 1 and 1000.

Sum:                        45
Average:                    22.50
Difference:                  5
Product:                   500
Distance:                    5
Maximum:                    25
Minimum:                    20
Hints:

The inputs will not be in green. That is to show user input.
There are 30 characters in the first line starting with "S" and ending with "5".
The ones digits are all aligned.
Use printf
Getting Started

Like our last exercise, we are going to do this exercise by writing the object that solves the problem first (in a source file called AlignedNumbers.java) and then testing it using code we write into Main.java. Using the techniques shown on the web page titled "How to Start Every Project in this Class" create a source file called AlignedNumbers.java as well as a file called Main.java.

Open up the AlignedNumbers.java file and replace the code with the code contained in the box below:

```
    /**
 * CS 135 Programming Fundamentals
 * CRN: [CHANGE THIS TO YOUR INFORMATION]
 * Assignment: AlignedNumbers
 * 
 * Statement of code ownership: I hereby state that I have written all of this
 * code and I have not copied this code from any other person or source.
 * 
 * @author [CHANGE THIS TO YOUR INFORMATION]
 */
package edu.sbcc.cs135;

/**
 * This class computes the statistics of two integers and prints them out.
 *
 */
public class AlignedNumbers {
    private int firstNumber;

    public void setFirstNumber(int firstNumber) {

    }

    public int getSum() {

    }

    public double getAverage() {

    }

    public int getDistance() {

    }

    public int getMinimum() {

    }

}
```

Look at this code and compare it to the UML diagram. Note which attributes and methods are missing and add them to the source code. You will also have to add Javadoc documentation to the code. This is especially relevant becuase you should give a (very) brief explantion of what the code does. Look to the problem description in the book for big hints on what to write. Be sure to reference the problem description above (and in the book) in order to solve this problem.

Next, using the same techique you used to create the AlignedNumbers.java file to create another file called Main.java. This is where your test code will go. Replace the code in that file with the code in the grey box below:

```
        /**
 * CS 135 Programming Fundamentals
 * CRN: [CHANGE THIS TO YOUR INFORMATION]
 * Assignment: AlignedNumbers
 * 
 * Statement of code ownership: I hereby state that I have written all of this
 * code and I have not copied this code from any other person or source.
 * 
 * @author [CHANGE THIS TO YOUR INFORMATION]
 */
package edu.sbcc.cs135;

import java.util.*;

/**
 * This class tests the AlignedNumbers object.
 *
 */
public class Main {

    /**
     * Test this code by asking for two numbers, computing the various stats,
     * and then printing it out.
     * 
     * @param args
     *            command line values. Not used in this example.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

Similar to the AlignedNumbers.java file go through Main.java and change the [CHANGE THIS TO YOUR INFORMATION] text to the proper items. There are two items to be changed.

You will also notice that Main.java does not contain any code to test the AlignedNumbers.java source code. Write some test routines based upon the problem description and follow the input and output examples closely.

Once you've written your code run the code by single clicking on Main.java in the package explorer and selecting Run->Run from the menu or using the keyboard shortcut. Examine the output. Does it do what you want? If not, how can you modify the code to do what you want?

**I have followed the instructions and filled in the remaining methods that are outlined from the UML. I am a bit stuck though as to where I need to insert my Scanner code and what to use as my constructors. Any help or tips on how to solve this would be great.**

**Btw I am new to coding in JAVA, this is probably our 5th assignment in the class and it is moving very quickly other newb tips would be awesome!**

Comment: You need to use the this keyword to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Yes, you do need to use a main method, that is the entry point for your program (i.e. where it starts). Anything you don't call from there won't be run. Can you give some more detail about what you are trying to accomplish with aligning numbers?

Comment: My proffessor gives us a UML to follow "which I have" [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4455325/sbcc/cs135/img/fundamentalDataTypes/E0402_AlignedNumbers.png)

Comment: My Proffessor explains that I should work like this"

Input first number: 20
Input second number: 25
You then print all of the statistics using the exact format below. Your printStats method must generate this exact format for any two integers between 1 and 1000.

Sum:                        45
Average:                    22.50
Difference:                  5
Product:                   500
Distance:                    5
Maximum:                    25
Minimum:                    20"

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you mean by your first question:

> I do not know what to write for the following "setFirstNumber" method,
>   would use my public AlignedNumbers method to do so?

By Java convention, set methods, are used to apply a value to one of your object's fields through an external call. In your case, I am not sure your `setFirstNumber` method even compiles since`fNumber` does not exist in the same scope.

A minor note, as general convention, when a class calls global variables and methods which are declared within it, we use the `this` keyword, so your method body would look like: `this.firstNumber = firstNumber;`

Your second question:

> Do I even have to worry about a main method?

Yes you do. All Java executable applications need to define a special method called `main`. This denotes the entry point of your application. In your case, so as to try and keep your current class as clean as possible, you might want to place your main method in another class which calls the class you have posted here and supplies it the argument it needs. This main method could also use the `Scanner` class to read input from the user.

Answer (score 0):

You are off to a good start.

Some facts that might help:

- Yes, to actually run the program you need a main method. `AlignedNumbers` is a class so you will then *instantiate* a new *instance* of `AlignedNumbers` using syntax like `AlignedNumbers an = new AlignedNumbers(<params go here>);`
- You should use the `return` keyword to return values from a function (like say, getSum)
- `setFirstNumber` will not compile as is because `fnumber` is undefined. I'm guessing that you meant to make `fnumber` a parameter. There are a few other mistakes like this as well.

Answer (score 0):

So, yes you do have to worry about a main method. You wouldn't be able to run this program without one. To use you class you would write something like ...

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.print("What is the first number: ");
         int firstNum = scan.nextInt();
         System.out.print("What is the second number: ");
         int secondNum = scan.nextInt();
         AlignedNumbers an = new AlignedNumbers(firstNum, secondNum)
         //above line instantiates new objects and sets original numbers
         int sum = an.getSum();//this would return sum. etc
    }
 }
```

The moral of the story is that you do need a main method. In the main method you can use the class that you have written.

Comment: This is making more sense. I am not sure however what to declare in my main method, as well as the "setFirstNumber". Is that when I would use the Scanner?

Comment: Your constructor sets the first number and the second number in the class.  It was my understanding from your code that setFirstNumber was just to change the first number after the fact. Is that correct?